# Not able to create markdown document from R even though code runs fine

Tags: r, wordpress, analytics, r-markdown, web-analytics

I am sorry if this sounds like a very basic question in Rmarkdown.

I am basically trying to read in some files (download my wordpress post statistics  from urls basically https://wordpress.com/stats/day/posts/myblog.wordpress.com?startDate=2015-01-01 etal

and then use `rbind`.

This is the basic data structure of the files.

```
                            V1   V2 year
1         Home page / Archives 1152 2011
2                  Hacker Poem  414 2011
3              Corporate Poems  294 2011
4                 For my child  232 2011
5           Poem on Steve Jobs  174 2011
6 I will never meet Steve Jobs  134 2011
```

I do get this warning message in imports but it works fine.

```
**> poem15=read.csv(a[7],header=F)
Warning message:
In scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
  EOF within quoted string**


ls()
rm(list=ls())
gc()
getwd()
a=dir()
a[3:7]
a[3]
poem11=read.csv(a[3],header=F,sep=",")
poem11$year=2011
a[4]
poem12=read.csv(a[4],header=F,sep=",")
poem12$year=2012
a[5]
poem13=read.csv(a[5],header=F,sep=",")
poem13$year=2013
a[6]
poem14=read.csv(a[6],header=F,sep=",")
poem14$year=2014
a[7]
poem15=read.csv(a[7],header=F)
poem15$year=2015
poem15=na.omit(poem15)
poetry = rbind(poem11,poem12,poem13,poem14,poem15)
poetry=poetry[order(poetry$V2),]
boxplot(poetry$V2~poetry$year)
```

But it gives this error when trying to knit it using RStudio

```
Quitting from lines 3-28 (code_boiler.spin.Rmd) 
Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> rbind -> rbind
Execution halted
```

Comment: seems like there is an opening quote somewhere in yout `poem15` file that is never closed. Open it in a text editor, find the lonely quote, and remove or close it.

Comment: that removed the warning but still rbind gives error only within rmarkdown

Comment: can you call `ncol(poemXX)` after each import to see what dataset has a different number of columns?

Comment: they are all 3 and they all are the same.

Comment: When you knit a document, the working directory is set to the directory the file is located in. Are you aware of this? In other words, are you positive that `dir()` returns what you expect when knitting?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you rbind different combinations of the "poems" for example just poem11 and poem12?

Answer (score 0):

You might try rmarkdown::render() or knitr::knit2html() if the knit HTML button doesn't work.

````
```{r}
x <- data.frame(V1=c('Home page / Archives','Hacker Poem','Corporate Poems','For my child','Poem on Steve Jobs','I will never meet Steve Jobs'), V2=c(1152,414,294,232,174,134), year=2011)
rbind(x,x)
```
````

Comment: knitr::knit2html()  gave the html doc but no output was there